# Why does downgrading my framework version and then upgrading again allow this .dll to load properly?

Tags: c#, .net

I am trying to automate some data collection using an Oscilloscope. I have a USB scope with plenty of [examples](https://www.tiepie.com/en/libtiepie-sdk/c-sharp). The examples worked just fine, but when I tried to create my own project things stopped working. I have mirrored their setup with respect to the `.dll` location and which is referenced in the project. Whenever the program tried to access any part of their `.dll` I continue to get

> An attempt was made to load a program with an incorrect format. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x8007000B)".

There is however, nothing wrong with the `.dll`s. They are copied and pasted straight from the examples.

After changing a single variable many times over I found out how to fix the issue, at least in the short term. I found that I was targeting a different framework than they were. They target `2.0` and I was targeting the current `4.6.1`. The page linked above says it should work with .NET 2.0 and newer. So I downgraded my project to `2.0` and now I do not get an exception when interacting with the `.dll`. Then if I upgraded to `4.6.1` it would continue to work.

My question is why, if possible to explain without their source code, does downgrading and upgrading again fix the issue?

Also, does this "fix" pose any long term issues that I need to be aware of?

Comment: Sounds like binding redirects to me.

Comment: You may have got this error because you had the 32 bit version of the dll and your project was x64 - or the other way round. When you switched frameworks your project got set to the correct versions. The [library offers 32 and 64 bit versions](https://www.tiepie.com/en/libtiepie-sdk/windows) - which one did you download and what's your project platform setting? Also, will this app have users? You may have to see which versions work on their PCs. See [this image](https://www.codeofclimber.ru/images/2015-04-10.right-net45-console-prefer-32bit-checkbox.png) for where to see your settings.

Comment: @stuartd I think you're on the right track. I have a baseline .sln on 4.6.1 that has never been downgraded (still throws exceptions on the .dll load). In that project I just tried changing the target platform in visual studio from Any CPU to x86 and to x64. It fails on Any CPU, fails on x86, and works on x64. So something somewhere is being changed to prefer x64 after the downgrade/upgrade. On the other projects I downgraded and upgraded I still have the target platform set to Any CPU.

I specifically downloaded only the 64 bit version.

Comment: Are you using source control?  The diff of before and after should reveal the cause.

Comment: @Amy That is a great idea. It was the :Prefer 32-bit" flag that changed. I had excluded this as an exact cause because I tried that earlier. However, since trying that I realized that there was a section of code I had removed that was apparently required. The documentation does not mark this code as required during startup, but I have to query the Library version before I am allowed to use it in any other way. If I do not query it, I get an error that looks very similar to the one I was getting originally. Very weird design, and lacking in documentation unfortunately.